# Passing variables into HSL color values in Three.JS

Tags: javascript, colors, three.js, hsl

I currently have 2 HSL colors set in my code:

```
scene.background = new THREE.Color("hsl(0, 100%, 50%)");
var light = new THREE.AmbientLight("hsl(180, 100%, 50%)");
```

I'm trying to pass a variable for 'hue' from my CSS in.

When I run this code, I'm able to see the 2 color variables I have defined in my CSS, which are 0 and 180 respectively:

```
var style = getComputedStyle(document.body);
console.log(style.getPropertyValue("--color-accent-hue")); // get accent hue color
console.log(style.getPropertyValue("--color-accent-hue-inverse")); // get accent hue inverse color
```

At the beginning of my code, I defined these as JS variables like this:

```
const colorAccentHue = style.getPropertyValue('--color-accent-hue');
const colorAccentHueInverse = style.getPropertyValue('--color-accent-hue-inverse');
```

then tried to call them within my `init()` function like this:

```
scene.background = new THREE.Color("hsl(colorAccentHue, 100%, 50%)");
var light = new THREE.AmbientLight("hsl(colorAccentHueInverse, 100%, 50%)");`
```

But I get nothing. Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (or string concatenation).

```
scene.background = new THREE.Color(`hsl(${colorAccentHue}, 100%, 50%)`);
var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(`hsl(${colorAccentHueInverse}, 100%, 50%)`);
```

Comment: Perfect. That was it!

Comment: @ZekeWattles Happy to help.